# Trying to run a local server with port forwarding behind a carrier grade network from ISP, but getting no connection with localhost

Tags: port-forwarding, nat, localhost, gaming, dmz

i'm trying to make a half life server by portforwarding trought my router. It didn't work, i checked it out, and my public IP and my WAN IP were different, then i realised that i was in a carrier grade network. I called the ISP, asked them if there was a way to make this happen without them have to port forward to my router and they said yes, the guy make my router as a DMZ host. That was what i needed, requests to my public ip to any port were passed trought and to my router and then my router would port forward only the port i was interrest in, port 27015, half-life server default's UDP port.

But it didn't work, i made sure that my localhost has a static IP and configured the DHCP to reserve one for me, made firewall rules to allow traffic on 27015 port, and that i was using all the correct ip adresses for my localhost, my default gateway, my wan adress and my public adress.

Me and the guy from the ISP talked again and we concluded that the port was closed somehow, i setup real quick a filezilla server, (i port forwarded 27015, as listening port and a range 11000-12000, to transfer files, both in the router and firewall rule), and asked him if he could list my home directory from my public ip and port 27015, IT WORKED, so everything was okay, checked with Wireshark.

Now i'm in a situation that i want this to work but not sure whats's going on, the ISP guy doesn't help much, and i think that either the DMZ he setup doesn't somehow allow UDP packets, since filezilla uses TCP and Half-life server used UDP, or there is a firewall on the ISP router blocking UDP packets or picking up that port 27015 isn't a common service.

I'm new to networking, trying to setup this more like a challenge, learned a lot doing and reading how to do things, please feel free to point any errors and suggest solutions. Also trying to do it this specific way, if i cant't make it, probably gonna try to use ngrok to make the game server work.